# Grouping top 3 results by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table:

```
+---------+--------------------+--------------------------+
| imd_id  | Total TRx per Plan |        plan name         |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------------+
| 1111005 | 397.1556           | Medicaid Illinois (Idpa) |
| 1111005 | 25.7691            | Self Pay                 |
| 1111005 | 24.4355            | Tricare North Region     |
| 1111005 | 15.0312            | 0                        |
| 1111005 | 8.8425             | 0                        |
| 1111005 | 8.3139             | 0                        |
| 1111005 | 7.0534             | 0                        |
| 1111005 | 6.2588             | 0                        |
| 1111005 | 6.0358             | Bravo Health             |
| 1111005 | 5.9872             | 0                        |
| 1111531 | 133.9664           | Medicaid Al              |
| 1111531 | 29.2318            | 0                        |
| 1111531 | 23.2499            | 0                        |
| 1111531 | 21.9774            | 0                        |
| 1111531 | 14.9269            | 0                        |
| 1111531 | 10.1903            | Self Pay                 |
| 1111531 | 5.4962             | 0                        |
| 1111531 | 5.3409             | Bcbs Federal             |
| 1111531 | 4.4801             | 0                        |
| 1111531 | 3.8003             | 0                        |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

and trying to generate data that looks like this

```
+---------+--------------------------+----------+---------------+-----------+----------------------+----------+
| imd_id  |      TopFirstPlan       | TopFirst | TopSecondPlan | TopSecond |    TopThirdPlan     | TopThird |
+---------+--------------------------+----------+---------------+-----------+----------------------+----------+
| 1111005 | Medicaid Illinois (Idpa) | 0.78     | Self Pay      | 0.05      | Tricare North Region | 0.04     |
| 1111531 | MEDICAID ALABAMA (AL)    | 0.5      | Self Pay      | 0.04      | Bcbs Federal         | 0.02     |
+---------+--------------------------+----------+---------------+-----------+----------------------+----------+
```

please note that the way the TOPFIRST, TOP SECOND, TOP THIRD are created is the corresponding `Total TRx per Plan` divided by the sum of the plans for that specific IMD_ID.

so far I have this:

```
 select distinct a.imd_id,'topone'=
    (select top 1 totalrxperplan 
        from book1 b
      where b.imd_id =  a.imd_id)/
      (select SUM(totalrxperplan) 
        from book1 b
        where b.imd_id = a.imd_id)
      ,'topplan2'=
      (select top 1 xifinplanname 
        from book1 b
      where b.imd_id =  a.imd_id)
from book1 a
order by 1 asc
```

this query will return:

```
+---------+--------------------------+----------+
| imd_id  |      TopFirstPlan1       | TopFirst |
+---------+--------------------------+----------+
| 1111005 | Medicaid Illinois (Idpa) | 79%      |
| 1111531 | MEDICAID ALABAMA (AL)    | 53%      |
+---------+--------------------------+----------+
```

but I need to add on the other columns.

Please note that we will `ignore the plan name where it is 0`

Comment: Can you explain what your "so far" query is supposed to represent? I'm not sure what the `TOP 1` inside the subquery is supposed to do - without its own `ORDER BY`, SQL Server is free to select any arbitrary matching row.

Comment: @AaronBertrand shalom aaron, ive updated

Comment: Are the values where plan name = 0 red herrings? I'm not sure why 'Self Pay' shows up as one of the top 3 rows for 1111531 unless we're supposed to ignore rows where plan name = 0. You also should make sure your sample data (`Medicaid al`) matches your desired output (`MEDICAID ALABAMA (AL)`) just for clarity.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks so much, yes we are supposed to ignore the 0's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #x(imd_id INT, totalrxperplan FLOAT, xifinplanname NVARCHAR(64));

INSERT #x VALUES
(1111005,397.1556 ,'Medicaid Illinois (Idpa)'),
(1111005,25.7691  ,'Self Pay                '),
(1111005,24.4355  ,'Tricare North Region    '),
(1111005,15.0312  ,'0                       '),
(1111005,8.8425   ,'0                       '),
(1111005,8.3139   ,'0                       '),
(1111005,7.0534   ,'0                       '),
(1111005,6.2588   ,'0                       '),
(1111005,6.0358   ,'Bravo Health            '),
(1111005,5.9872   ,'0                       '),
(1111531,133.9664 ,'Medicaid Al             '),
(1111531,29.2318  ,'0                       '),
(1111531,23.2499  ,'0                       '),
(1111531,21.9774  ,'0                       '),
(1111531,14.9269  ,'0                       '),
(1111531,10.1903  ,'Self Pay                '),
(1111531,5.4962   ,'0                       '),
(1111531,5.3409   ,'Bcbs Federal            '),
(1111531,4.4801   ,'0                       '),
(1111531,3.8003   ,'0                       ');
```

Now the query:

```
WITH cte1(id,pn,s) AS 
(
    SELECT imd_id, xifinplanname, 
      ROUND(totalrxperplan/SUM(totalrxperplan) OVER (PARTITION BY imd_id),2,1)
    FROM #x WHERE xifinplanname <> '0'
),
cte2(id,pn,s,rn) AS 
(
    SELECT id,pn,s,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY s DESC)
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  TopFirstPlan  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN pn END),
  TopFirst      = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN s  END),
  TopSecondPlan = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN pn END),
  TopSecond     = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN s  END),
  TopThirdPlan  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN pn END),
  TopThird      = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN s  END)
FROM cte2 
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY id;
```

If my assumption is right that the output numbers don't match yours because you want to include even '0' plans in the total, just not in the results, then you can just shift the where clause:

```
WITH cte1(id,pn,s) AS 
(
    SELECT imd_id, xifinplanname, 
      ROUND(totalrxperplan/SUM(totalrxperplan) OVER (PARTITION BY imd_id), 2, 1)
    FROM #x -- < -- removed where clause from here
),
cte2(id,pn,s,rn) AS 
(
    SELECT id,pn,CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), s),ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY s DESC)
    FROM cte1 WHERE pn <> '0' -- <-- moved where clause here
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  TopFirstPlan  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN pn END),
  TopFirst      = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN s  END),
  TopSecondPlan = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN pn END),
  TopSecond     = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN s  END),
  TopThirdPlan  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN pn END),
  TopThird      = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN s  END)
FROM cte2 
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: The first CTE gets the percentage of the total for each id/plan name, using the OVER() clause. The second CTE takes those values and also calculates the rank (ordered by highest percentage) where the plan name is something real. The final query against the CTEs takes only the 1, 2 and 3 rank from the CTE and groups by id. The MAX() allows you to treat each rank separately.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the key is to enumerate the groups by their total within each imd_id.  You can do this using the windows function row_number().

The final query looks something like:

```
select imd_id,
       max(case when therank = 1 then plan_name end) as firstplan,
       max(case when therank = 1 then tot/imd_tot end) as firstplan_ratio,
       ...
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by imd_id order by tot desc) as therank,
             sum(tot) over (partition by imd_id) as imd_tot
      from (select imd_id  plan_name, sum(total_trx_per_plan) as tot
            from t
            group by imd_id  plan_name
           ) t
     ) t
group by imd_id
```

Comment: getting this Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'tot'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You seemed to want the market share of the plans within the imd_id.  "tot" is the total for the plan in the imd and imd_tot is the total for all plans in it.  I left out a "then", which is I am fixing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Aaron's grand total, as opposed to the per-id total, is what the OP wanted, so here's my suggestion, basically what Aaron suggested but with different fractional values:

**Updated to correct bad copy, and to account for '0' rule.**

```
with R1 as (
  select
    imd_id,
    [plan name],
    1e0*[Total TRx per Plan]/sum([Total TRx per Plan]) over (partition by imd_id) as pct,
    row_number() over (
      partition by imd_id
      order by case when [plan name] = '0' then -1 else [Total TRx per Plan] end desc
    ) as rn
  from @Test
) 
  select
    imd_id,
    max(case when rn=1 then [plan name] end) as TopFirstPlan,
    max(case when rn=1 then pct end) as TopFirst,
    max(case when rn=2 then [plan name] end) as TopSecondPlan,
    max(case when rn=2 then pct end) as TopSecond,
    max(case when rn=3 then [plan name] end) as TopThirdPlan,
    max(case when rn=3 then pct end) as TopThird
  from R1
  where rn <= 3
  group by imd_id
  order by imd_id
```

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @Steve I think you're right about grand total vs total within a specific imd_id, however that math doesn't seem to match the desired results either.

Comment: I think this is because the grand total needs to account for plans where plan name = '0', but the results should only show those whose plans are *not* named '0'.

Comment: Sorry, that was a terrible copy-and-paste on my part. Fixed, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with such query:

```
WITH totals AS (
  SELECT imd_id, sum(t_trx_per_plan) AS ttl
    FROM plans
   GROUP BY imd_id),
ranks(imd_id,t_trx_per_plan,plan_name,prc,rank) AS (
  SELECT p.imd_id,p.t_trx_per_plan,p.plan_name,
    CAST(p.t_trx_per_plan / t.ttl * 100 AS NUMERIC(5,2)) AS prc,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY p.imd_id
        ORDER BY (p.t_trx_per_plan / t.ttl * 100) DESC) AS rank
    FROM plans p
    JOIN totals t ON t.imd_id = p.imd_id
   WHERE p.plan_name != '0')
SELECT
    ttl.imd_id,
    f.plan_name AS "FirstPlan",f.prc AS "First",
    s.plan_name AS "SecondPlan",s.prc AS "Second",
    t.plan_name AS "ThirdPlan",t.prc AS "Third"
  FROM totals ttl
  LEFT JOIN ranks f ON f.imd_id = ttl.imd_id AND f.rank = 1
  LEFT JOIN ranks s ON s.imd_id = ttl.imd_id AND s.rank = 2
  LEFT JOIN ranks t ON t.imd_id = ttl.imd_id AND t.rank = 3;
```

First CTE `totals` is giving list of `imd_id`'s with their total transactions per plan. Second CTE `ranks` is ranking plans. Note, that I've used `rank()` functions, which will yield equal rankings in case plans has the same number of transactions per plan. If you want to properly treat such cases, you need to use `row_number()` window function and add extra `ORDER BY` column into the `OVER` clause, the only possibility is to use:

```
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY p.imd_id
    ORDER BY (p.t_trx_per_plan / t.ttl * 100) DESC, p.plan_name) AS rank
```

You can check output [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51cac/17).